# How do you delete a Super User account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, delete

Over on Super User, I logged in accidentally with another Gmail account, and created a new profile.

Because of all the cookie/JavaScript/IP hocus-pocus, instead of a decent no-fuzz PHP login, Super User keeps coming up with this new account and logs in automatically. After a force clean of all cookies, dumping the cache and a restart, I managed to login with a different user account.

Now, how do I get rid of this accidental account?

Comment: Beware to use the right Gmail account to log in to Meta here, and then associate your Super User account and Meta accounts at, for example, http://superuser.com/users/15299?tab=accounts

Comment: Closed as a dupe of a newer question since the current answers are all incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

You can email `team@superuser.com` and ask them to merge the accounts or delete one of them.

But, before you do so, please try this (may not work, but it's interesting to know for sure whether it does or does not):

1. Log in with the account you want to keep.
2. Go to your profile page.
3. Click *add openid*.
4. Log in with the wrong/accidental openid.
5. Tell us what the site says. (Does it offer you to merge the accounts? Does it fail? Something else?)

Note that PHP is one of many serverside languages in use these days. This website does not run PHP, so it makes no sense to talk about a "PHP login". I would also argue that you have it backwards when you say that such a login system is "no-fuzz", thereby implying that openid is cumbersome: what could possibly be easier than registering to a website *without* having to think up a new username and password?

Answer (score 2):

"Superuser keeps comming up with this new account and logs in automatically. After a force clean of all cookies and cache documents and a restart"

I always found the logout button works well for this very purpose.

Comment: But, just in case: clicking Logout does need another click on the Logout button -- see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21667/logged-out-but-still-logged-in for a very descriptive manual :-)

Answer (score 2):

Its in the [help](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/691/how-do-you-delete-a-super-user-account) - you contact stackexchange using the contact us link, and set your profile to "delete me"