# How can I delete superuser account?

Tags: discussion

I don't want to keep my account on superuser because this site doesn't suit my taste, how can I delete it?

I have looked into my account but it seems there isn't any option like that, but maybe I am not trying hard enough. Or maybe it can not be deleted?

Answer (score 6):

Its in the [help](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/691/how-do-you-delete-a-super-user-account) - you contact stackexchange using the contact us link, and set your profile to "delete me".

I'd add the problems you've had *might* be solved by reading through the help, since your other question and this were *both* off topic for SU proper

Answer (score 4):

From [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

> The [Help Center explains](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) that there are two cases:
>
> **If your account has interacted with the site** by voting or posting, go to the [Contact Support page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and fill out the form. One of
>   the items in the topics drop-down list is for account deletion.
>
> You can also get to that page via the "contact us" section on the site
>   footer. Please note that account deletion is not instant. It might
>   take several days for your request to be processed.
>
> Due to [a known
>   issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/further-anonymize-deleted-accounts-by-changing-the-username-prior-to-deletion),
>   you might want to change your username before deleting the account.
>
> **If your account has never voted or posted a question or answer more than once**, you should see a self-delete option on your user page
>   next to the *edit* link:
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> Either of these procedures cover deleting your account on **one
>   specific site**.
>
> **Content you've posted on the site** [is owned by you but licensed to Stack
>   Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post),
>   and you therefore cannot request that it be deleted with your account.
>
> Also of note, we automatically cull old inactive accounts as
>   documented on the blog:
>
> - [When is an Account Abandoned?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/)